# Response.Redirect(url) shows a 301 and a 302 in the firefox developer console

Tags: c#, asp.net

two pages are hosted in iis, the mainpage contains a link:

```
<a href="https://localhost/ijustredirect">Go to "i just redirect"</a>
```

and the ijustredirect page contains:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Response.Redirect("https://localhost/mainpage");
}
```

on its default site.

the picture shows part of the firefox developer console, why is there a 301 followed by a 302?
even disregarding that one is temporary and the other is a permanent "notice", shouldnt there be only one or whats the reason for "ijustredirect" and "/ijustredirect/" ?

firefox was already showing the mainpage, then i clicked on the link and it loaded up the second page which immediately redirected me back to mainpage - thats how to lines in the network tab where created.

[image: 301 and 302 right after another]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that ASP.NET will automatically redirect you from `ijustredirect` to `ijustredirect/` so just change the hyperlink to

```
<a href="https://localhost/ijustredirect/">Go to "i just redirect"</a>
```

to avoid this

Comment: adding the / at the end of the link and also changing the Response.Redirect to: Response.Redirect("https://localhost/mainpage/") solved the issue. It worked before but to understand the process better this answer was helpfull.